# bootstrap slider images are not displayed

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the code,

```
 <header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url(http://s23.postimg.org/9nq4ybppn/home_slider1.jpg one);"></div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2>Caption 1</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url(http://s23.postimg.org/su3c1i67f/home_slider2.jpg two);"></div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2>Caption 2</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url(http://s23.postimg.org/v17kpfbhn/home_slider3.jpg three);"></div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2>Caption 3</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 </header>
```

I m using bootstrap, but it is not working.. images are not displayed..

May i know what i am missing..?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ### [Via data attributes](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#via-data-attributes-4)
>
> Use data attributes to easily control the position of the carousel.
>   `data-slide` accepts the keywords `prev` or `next`, which alters the
>   slide position relative to its current position. Alternatively, use
>   `data-slide-to` to pass a raw slide index to the carousel
>   `data-slide-to="2"`, which shifts the slide position to a particular
>   index beginning with `0`.
>
> **The `data-ride="carousel"` attribute is used to mark a carousel as
>   animating starting at page load**. It cannot be used in combination with
>   (redundant and unnecessary) explicit JavaScript initialization of the
>   same carousel.

My guess is that you have to add the `data-ride="carousel"` to the carousel.

**Edit:**
I've also noticed [the example on the Bootstrap website](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-examples) uses a slightly different html:

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
        <img src="..." alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="..." alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see a carousel on that page :P

Comment: Just look at the bootstrap documentation (link in my post) and copy-paste the example. Add your image urls and you should be done.

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use this Code, maybe its works good.

```
<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <div class="fill" style="background: url(http://s23.postimg.org/9nq4ybppn/home_slider1.jpg) no-repeat center center;background-size: 100%;min-height: 500px; "></div>

                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2>Caption 1</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="fill" style="background: url(http://s23.postimg.org/su3c1i67f/home_slider2.jpg) no-repeat center center;background-size: 100%;min-height: 500px; "></div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2>Caption 2</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="fill" style="background: url(http://s23.postimg.org/v17kpfbhn/home_slider3.jpg) no-repeat center center;background-size: 100%;min-height: 500px; "></div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2>Caption 3</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Works great! I need to mention that this is not mobile friendly. Nonetheless, thank you!